# Snowflake failed queries alerts in real time

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there any way I can get the failed queries running in snowflake in real-time. Is that even possible?
I have seen this which is about notification integration in snowflake, what kind of notifications does it send? Any ideas or suggestions, please help me.
[https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-notification-integration.html'](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-notification-integration.html%27)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowflake does not have an alert mechanism for failed queries.

For "real" real-time, your client calling the query should check the query's result and may produce an alert when the query fails.

If you mean "near" real-time monitoring any failed queries, you may schedule a job that will query information_schema.query_history every X minute(s).

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html